# Return change, without using list of currency

Tags: c++, algorithm

For homework I need to make a program in C++, that returns change in coins. So far I made it, and it works, except one problem, I cant get out of the while loop:

This is the code,

```
int calculating(int value,  int start_value) {
cout << "func" << endl;
int counter = 0;
while(value >= 0) {
    if (value - start_value >= 0) {
        value = value - start_value;
        counter++;          
    } else {            
        cout << start_value << " : " << counter << endl;
        start_value = start_value / 2;
        counter = 0;
    }
}
return 0;
}
```

Can someone please give me some idea how to perfect this code. Thanks

Comment: What are the rules of giving change? What is start value and value?

Comment: Did you mean `while(value > 0)`??

Comment: @user2040251 It need to be in standard currency nominations 10, 5, 2, 1 whole numbers

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ if I try the code like that I dont get the right answer

Comment: @depecheSoul That may be because the function always returns the value `0`.

Comment: @depecheSoul `do {} while(value > 0)` may be then?

Comment: @interjay I am not interesten in that part. I want to get the listing right

Comment: I think it's not about _perfection_ but getting it working at all ...

Comment: @depecheSoul Can you explain what functionality you are trying to achive?

Comment: You should read the chapter on integer arithmetic. There's no need for the counter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
while(value >= 0) {
    if (value - start_value >= 0) {
        value = value - start_value;
        counter++;          
    } else {            
        cout << start_value << " : " << counter << endl;
        start_value = start_value / 2;
        counter = 0;
    }
}
```

if  `value - start_value < 0` (what likely is the case at some iteration assuming how you try to use it) you divide `start_value = start_value / 2` infinitely.

example:

```
calculating( value=4,  start_value=3)
```

step 1:

```
while(4) {
    if (1 >= 0) {
        value = 1;
```

step 2:

```
while(1) {
    if(-2) //  false
    } else {            
            cout << start_value << " : " << counter << endl;
            start_value = start_value / 2;
    }
```

and so on , value = 1, start_value = start_value / 2;

Comment: I dont think it is infinite because I am using int data types, 1/2 gives me 0, at int datat type

Comment: stop condition can't be triggered since you are comparing value >= 0 and just dividing start_value = start_value / 2;

Comment: @depecheSoul debug this with values 4,3 to see what is going on, 4,3 are fantastic numbers

Answer (score 1):

`value` will be at least `0` everytime, you should try `while (value > 0)`

Comment: For example 8, I get that I have one of 5 currency, and one of two currency

Comment: The code do what you say, that is for sure! Can you explain what you wnat it to do?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `break` to get out of a loop.

Answer (score 1):

As you are using objects of type int then I would write the condition of the loop as

```
while (value != 0 )
```

Your code contains a logical error that if the value will be equal to 0 then the loop will continue to execute.

Also I would made parameters having type unsigned int instead of int.

And this condition

```
if (value - start_value >= 0)
```

would be better to change to

```
if (value >= start_value )
```